# how to set the AutoIncrement-property of table column in adox?

Tags: c#, ms-access, adox

as i explain in the title, i cant set the property to the column:

```
Catalog cat = new Catalog();
        Table tableCustomer = new Table();
        Table tableAddresses = new Table();

        try
        {                
            //Create the table Customer and it's fields. 
            tableCustomer.Name = "Customer";
            tableCustomer.Columns.Append("Customer_ID", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adInteger);
            //column.ParentCatalog = cat;
            //column.Name = "Customer_ID";
            //column.Type = ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adInteger;
            //column.Properties["AutoIncrement"].Value = true;

            //tableCustomer.Columns.Append(column);

            tableCustomer.Keys.Append("PrimaryKEy", KeyTypeEnum.adKeyPrimary, "Customer_ID");
            tableCustomer.Columns["Customer_ID"].Properties["AutoIncrement"].Value = true;
            tableCustomer.Columns.Append("Name", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar, 50);
            tableCustomer.Columns.Append("Email", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar, 50);
            tableCustomer.Columns.Append("TelNumber", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar, 32);
            tableCustomer.Columns.Append("Fax", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar, 32);
            tableCustomer.Columns.Append("AdressCounter", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adSmallInt);

            tableAddresses.Name = "Addresses";
            tableAddresses.Columns.Append("Address_ID", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adInteger);
            tableAddresses.Keys.Append("PrimaryKEy", KeyTypeEnum.adKeyPrimary, "Address_ID");
            tableAddresses.Columns.Append("Customer_ID", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adInteger);
            tableAddresses.Keys.Append("ForeignKey", KeyTypeEnum.adKeyForeign, "Customer_ID", "Customer", "Customer_ID");
            tableAddresses.Columns.Append("Street", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar, 50);
            tableAddresses.Columns.Append("PostalCode", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar, 10);
            tableAddresses.Columns.Append("City", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar, 50);

            cat.Create("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "Data Source=" + Application.StartupPath
                + "\\Customers.mdb" + "; Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5");
            cat.Tables.Append(tableCustomer);
            cat.Tables.Append(tableAddresses);


            //Now Close the database
            ADODB.Connection con = cat.ActiveConnection as ADODB.Connection;
            if (con != null)
                con.Close();


            result = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result = false;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (!result)
            {
                ADODB.Connection con = cat.ActiveConnection as ADODB.Connection;
                if (con != null)
                    con.Close();
                File.Delete(Application.StartupPath + "\\Customers.mdb");
            }                 
        }
        cat = null;
```

i am getting an error, that the object in not found after executing the following line:

```
tableCustomer.Columns["Customer_ID"].Properties["AutoIncrement"].Value = true;
```

the error is that the object is not found.
but in all solutions in vb, they solve it like i wrote.
what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the `"Customer_ID"` column like you did in the commented lines of your code. According to [this source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/82849127-2576-4db1-bcf1-eb553b5f64eb/autoincrement-property?forum=adodotnetdataproviders), you missed to set the `ParentCatalog` property for the `Column`.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set the `ParentCatalog` for the column you wish to set properties on:

```
tableCustomer.Keys.Append("PrimaryKEy", KeyTypeEnum.adKeyPrimary, "Customer_ID");
tableCustomer.Columns["Customer_ID"].ParentCatalog = cat;
tableCustomer.Columns["Customer_ID"].Properties["AutoIncrement"].Value = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

your answers are both right.
but just, the catalog must be created before. 
here is the modified version:

```
Catalog cat = new Catalog();
        Table tableCustomer = new Table();
        Table tableAddresses = new Table();

        cat.Create("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "Data Source=" + Application.StartupPath
          + "\\Customers.mdb" + "; Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5");

        ADODB.Connection con = new Connection();
        string connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "Data Source="
            + Application.StartupPath + "\\Customers.mdb";

        try
        {
            con.Open(connString);
            cat.ActiveConnection = con;

            //Create the table Customer and it's fields. 
            tableCustomer.Name = "Customer";
            tableCustomer.Columns.Append("Customer_ID", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adInteger);
            tableCustomer.Keys.Append("PrimaryKEy", KeyTypeEnum.adKeyPrimary, "Customer_ID");
            tableCustomer.Columns["Customer_ID"].ParentCatalog = cat;
            tableCustomer.Columns["Customer_ID"].Properties["AutoIncrement"].Value = true;
            tableCustomer.Columns.Append("Name", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar, 50);
            tableCustomer.Columns.Append("Email", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar, 50);
            tableCustomer.Columns.Append("TelNumber", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar, 32);
            tableCustomer.Columns.Append("Fax", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar, 32);
            tableCustomer.Columns.Append("AdressCounter", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adSmallInt);

            tableAddresses.Name = "Addresses";
            tableAddresses.Columns.Append("Address_ID", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adInteger);
            tableAddresses.Keys.Append("PrimaryKEy", KeyTypeEnum.adKeyPrimary, "Address_ID");
            tableAddresses.Columns["Address_ID"].ParentCatalog = cat;
            tableAddresses.Columns["Address_ID"].Properties["AutoIncrement"].Value = true;
            tableAddresses.Columns.Append("Customer_ID", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adInteger);
            tableAddresses.Keys.Append("ForeignKey", KeyTypeEnum.adKeyForeign, "Customer_ID", "Customer", "Customer_ID");
            tableAddresses.Columns.Append("Street", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar, 50);
            tableAddresses.Columns.Append("PostalCode", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar, 10);
            tableAddresses.Columns.Append("City", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar, 50);

            //cat.Create("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "Data Source=" + Application.StartupPath
            //    + "\\Customers.mdb" + "; Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5");
            cat.Tables.Append(tableCustomer);
            cat.Tables.Append(tableAddresses);


            //Now Close the database
            //ADODB.Connection con = cat.ActiveConnection as ADODB.Connection;
            if (con != null)
                con.Close();


            result = true;
        }
```