# Unable to set autonumber to column in table create in Access DB using C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am creating a table with a column named "ID" and I am trying to set that column to autoincrement, but it keeps erroring out with the following error.

> "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Item cannot be found in
> the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal.'"

```
private void createDatabaseToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //cat.Create("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
     //         "Data Source=C:/Users/Richard/Documents/Test_ProjectBillTest.mdb;" + "Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5");
    
     var cat = new Catalog();
     var accountTable = new Table();
         
     var accountKey = new Key();
     var cDetailsTable = new Table();
     var cDetailsKey = new Key();

     cat.Create(AC.GetConnectionString());

     //Create the Account table & columns
     accountTable.Name = "Account";
     accountTable.Columns.Append("ID", DataTypeEnum.adInteger, 4);     
        
     accountTable.Keys.Append("PrimaryKey", KeyTypeEnum.adKeyPrimary, "ID", null, null);
     accountTable.Columns["ID"].Properties["autoincrement"].Value = true;

     cat.Tables.Append(accountTable);

     var dBcon = cat.ActiveConnection as OleDbConnection;
     if (dBcon != null) dBcon.Close();
     MessageBox.Show("Database Created Successfully");
}
```

I have rewritten this line `accountTable.Columns["ID"].Properties["autoincrement"].Value = true;`, but it still errors out.

But, with that line commented out, the code runs, creates the table & column, but its not setup to autoincrement.

Comment: Try ``accountTable.Columns["ID"].ParentCatalog = cat;`` before autoincrement property setting. See here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30378351/how-to-set-the-autoincrement-property-of-table-column-in-adox)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where "catalog" came from?

And creating columns in some data table in ADO.NET has ZERO to do with wanting to create a table in Access.

If you looking to create a table in a Access database? Then in near all cases, you have to execute DDL commands in SQL (data definition language).

Hence, to say create a table called PeopleTest, then this would work:

```
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.AccessDB))
        {
            conn.Open();
            string strSQL =
                @"CREATE TABLE tblPeopleTest
                (ID AutoIncrement,
                FirstName VARCHAR(40),
                LastName VARCHAR(40),
                BirthDay Datetime,
                constraint ID_PK PRIMARY KEY(ID))
                ";

            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Table tblPeopletest created");
    }
```

So, you first need to open a valid connection to the database.

You can then use DDL commands to create a table, or even DDL commands to add columns to a existing table.

Once the above table been created, then of course you are free to add new rows, or use that created table like any existing table in the Access database.